# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined in my React App

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image: Error I Got for my code]

I have been getting this error in my code the entire code can be found on [my github account](https://github.com/viveksuarez7/Widget.git)

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const onBodyClick = (event) => {
        if (ref.current && ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
            return;
        }
        setOpen(false);
    };
    document.body.addEventListener('click', onBodyClick);

    return () => {
        document.body.removeEventListener('click', onBodyClick);
    }
}, [])

const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    if (option.value === selected.value) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `options`?

Comment: I think, selected is undefined and it can not read value because of that. You can console.log(selected) above the if and check if it has the expected value

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question along with the error message as formatted plain text. From the error message image it seems either `option` is undefined (unlikely since you are mapping over *some* `options` array) or `selected` is undefined. Please show where these values (`options` and `selected`) come from.

Answer (score 0):

**Just add a selected prop to you DropDown component in App.js** like this:

```js
const showDropdown = () => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/Dropdown') {
        return <Dropdown options={options} selected={0}/>
    }
}
```

Notice the  `selected={0}`

Another way to come over this would be to check that a selected prop was provided:

```js
  const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    if ( selected && (option.value === selected.value)) {
      return null;
    }
```

And you are good to go!

### [image: translate component]

Details
When you hit the /Dropdown endpoint, your dropdown component is directly mounted/rendered, thus the `renderedOptions` function is called.

```js
// Dropdown.js
  return (
    <div ref={ref} className="ui form">
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">{label}</label>
        <div
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
          className={`ui selection dropdown ${open ? 'visible active' : ''}`}
        >
          <i className="dropdown icon"/>
          <div className="text">{selected.label}</div>
          <div className={`menu ${open ? 'visible transition' : ''}`}>
            {renderedOptions}  { <-------- this is called at first render }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

That means your if statement in that function is analysed

```js
 const renderedOptions = options.map((option) => {
    if (option.value === selected.value) { /* <-- value in select.value is undefined because you did not provide it to your component */
      return null;
    }
```

unfortunately, you did not provide a selected value to your component in App.js

```js
// Dropdown.js

const Dropdown = ({ options, selected, onSelectedChange,label}) => {

// code
}



// app.js
const showDropdown = () => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/Dropdown') {
        return <Dropdown options={options}/> //  <--- no  selected here
    }
}
```

Comment: The options over here is the array provided in app.js so .The dropdown component will coantain the various colors and not the Translate Component  which you have shown hereThe options you are presenting are described in Translate Component You can check your solution again

Comment: I just showed a solution with the translate componenet that uses the dropdown. If the image confuses, just follow the explanation logic. There lies your error.  Now if you don't see the undefined error , your question is fixed, and you may ask another question about seeing your colors.